# docke named volume doesn't appear

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have the following two docker compose files:

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2.3'

services:


# test11 service
  test11:
    build: test11/.
    image: "test11"
```

and

docker-compose.yml (file inside the folder named test11 that contains Dockerfile and the following docker-compose ):

```
version: '2.3'

networks:
  citrixhoneypot_local:

services:

# CitrixHoneypot service
  test11:
    build: .
    container_name: test11
    restart: always
    networks:
     - citrixhoneypot_local
    ports:
     - "443:443"
    image: "test11:2006"
    #    read_only: true
    volumes:
     - test11:/opt/test11/logs
volumes:
  test11:
    driver:local
```

when i run `docker-compose up --build` for the first file, everything seems ok and the container build and i can run `exec -it sh`  on it and get access.

but the problem is that the volume isn't made in the path
`/var/lib/docker/volumes` and i can't find it there.

also when i write in `/opt/test11/logs` from inside the docker container no file is made under `/var/lib/docker/volumes` .

I tried this with `bind path` too. same problem with that too.

Comment: When docker-compose creates a volume, it prefixes the volume name with the docker-compose directory name (like it also does for the container names). So if your project is in the directory 'my-project', then the volume will be called 'my-project_test11'. Can you see the volume with `docker volume ls`?

Comment: i checked all of the volumes under ```/var/lib/docker/volumes``` nothing from this container.
i'll check ```docker volume ls``` and send result here . thanks

Comment: no it isn't made and it's not appear in ```docker volume ls```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be directly looking in `/var/lib/docker` at all.  If you want to read the log files on your host, use bind-mount syntax, `volumes: [./logs:/opt/test11/logs]`.

Comment: @DavidMaze
I tried it with bind-mount too. actually whole day i was dealing with bind-mount solution it didn't work

Comment: What does happen?  If you use debugging tools like `docker-compose exec`, can you find the logs inside the container somewhere?  The two files don't use the same image (you build `test11:latest` but run `test11:2006`); is this a potential source of trouble?